# Java - asynchronous methods with return value

Tags: java, asynchronous, casting

I have a question about asynchronous method calls in java, especially about the response value of the async method.

The situation is the following:

The async method I want to call is..

```
public void getSpeed(IResponseListener listener) {
....
}
```

The interface of the listener is...

```
interface IResponseListener {
    public void response(ResponseEvent event);
}
```

This method is called when the async method has a response value

My problem now is that the class `ResponseEvent` has an attribute `response` that can be of any type (`boolean,float,String...)`and in the implementation of the interface `IResponseListener` I have to cast the value...

```
IResponseListener listener = new IResponseListener {

    public void response(ResponseEvent event) {
        float f = (float)event.response;
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution to handle this? I think the bad thing is that the response listener HAS to know the type of the response! 
Is there a better solution to handle asynchronous calls that want to give a response even if the response can be of any type?

Comment: Have you thought about using [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)?

Comment: You should create a getter for the response in the `ResponseEvent` and parameterize (use generics) for the ResponseEvent using one of the boxing classes (`Float` in this case).

Comment: On what basis does the datatype of the response property vary?

Comment: Your problem seems to be with Java's typing rules. The fact that there's an async method involved is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm just curious, but why would the return type be of different type? Are you reusing the same listener class in multiple places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done as @nico_ekito says...Or use your existing solution. It is a problem that you don't know the result type.

Anyway, you could do some adjustments and let the ResponseEvent class do the casting for you.

**ResponseListener.java**

```
interface IResponseListener {
    void response(ResponseEvent event);
}
```

**ResponseEvent.java**

```
public class ResponseEvent {

   private Object response;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public <T> T getResponse() {
       return (T)response;
   }

   public <T> void setResponse(T response) {
       this.response = response;
   }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IResponseListener listener = new IResponseListener() {
    public void response(ResponseEvent event) {
        float f = event.getResponse();
    } 
};
```

Please note that you will get a `ClassCastException` if your type is something other than what you expect it to be.

Comment: This is called "type capture," no? Also, the OP is hoping to avoid the ClassCastException, so I think using a visitor pattern approach will work best here.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of these answers are starting to look like this->

```
public interface Function<Args, Value>
{
  public Value call(Args args);
}
```

Your return type doesn't matter--if it can return multiple types, then the "multiple types" are a type...might I suggest a type of JSON considering what you're looking at?

The reality is you can't expect your handler to know the type in advance so you need to specify that. Whether this is with the return type or the class is up to you.

I could easily see doing a class hierarchy:

```
public class ResponseString implements Function<Args, String>; 
public class ResponseNumber implements Function<Args, Number>;
...
public class ResponseType implements Function<Args, Type>;
```

or simply creating a type that has all the information you need. The long and short is that the method can DEFINE what it expects for the types and you have the ability to extend them. Keep in mind that response could also be a Function which could be executed. There's nothing wrong with knowing what to DO with something and not knowing what it is ->

Example->

```
//Admittedly I'd probably have a "Procedure or VoidFunction interface as well".
public yourMethod(Function<String args, Function<String,?> handler)
{
  String hello = "hello";
  Function<String,?> function = handler.call(hello);
  function.call(hello); 
}
```

I hope this helps. Sometimes there's no reason to go this far, and sometimes there is. You don't know the type--it seems like maybe you're hoping someone else will provide it and this can do that for you while remaining strict.

EDIT:
  the example of have for this in one framework is:

```
  Applcation.openDialog(Dialog dialog, Callable<Boolean> onClose);
```

This returns true of the dialog cleans up and closes and false if not. I don't really care what happens here, I do care that it tells me yes, close it, or no don't.

Comment: A side note--if you tell us what you're trying to do with the response you'll see less complex answers!

Comment: thank you for your great effort but I think the response of @nekman comes closest to my needs ;)

Comment: @TobiWeißhaar His answer is a very solid answer, you don't need functional abstraction unless you really need it (and then it can make something stupidly simple)

Answer (score 1):

Use Java generics:

```
interface IResponseListener<T> {
    public void response(T response);
}
```

Then, in an anonymous class:

```
IResponseListener listener = new IResponseListener<Float> {

    public void response(Float response) {
        float f = response;
    }
}
```

Comment: The listener still has to know the type of the response; see the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: You will need to define an `IResponseListener` for each datatype you want to support,and have a parent dispatch method that makes a call relying on runtime type resolution / overloading to reach the correct listener (roughly something like this: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ProxyVisitorPattern?_sscc=t). Alternatively, you can do a a big ugly `if`/`else` chain using `instanceof` to resolve and downcast the type of the Response object (but don't tell anyone here).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is correct, but if you are going to handle the return value differently, why not overload the response method with different type of objects that you would expect. Just a suggestion..

```
interface InterfaceName{
    void response(float responseVal);
    void response(boolean responseVal);
    ...
}
```